# Deploy webapp developed using django on an android device on the local network

Tags: android, django, deployment, jetty, django-wsgi

I'm using a pandaboard running android os. I want to deploy a webapp developed using django on the local wifi network so that any device in the wifi range can connect to the wifi netowrk and access the webapp through the browser. What can I use to deploy it? Java webapps can be deployed using i-jetty. But, anything like wsgi for android?

Comment: I found this link:

http://keniallee.blogspot.in/2012/08/django-14-for-android-only-dev-runserver.html